# Why are my disabled networks still interfering?

Tags: wireless-networking, wifi-configuration

As near as I can tell (using tools like WiFi Explorer) disabling my Comcast router's xfininti/XFINITY hotspot(s) only hides them. The antennas appear to still be on (the MAC addresses associated with the Comcast hardware still appear in my list as active, but just without a network name) resulting on overall poor quality and performance for my WiFi. Is that what's going on? If so, how do I actually turn off my xfininti/XFINITY hotspot(s) completely so that I don't get interference from them?

Comment: Comcast shares your internet connection from your Comcast router with the public as a hotspot - you may want to check with customer service if this could be the source _(unsure if they allow customers to opt-out)_

Comment: See the methods as [recommended by Comcast](https://www.xfinity.com/support/articles/disable-xfinity-wifi-home-hotspot).

Comment: @JW0914 So I'm not hallucinating then: The antennas are still on and blasting even though I've "disabled" (actually just hidden) the xfinity/XFINITY hotspot?

Comment: @harrymc That's what I did, but the question is: Does "disable" really just mean "hide", without actually turning off the antennas.

Comment: Doing both the described methods is the most I can advise. If no knowledgeable Comcast user steps up here, Comcast Support is your best bet.

Comment: Just to make sure: you have your own Wi-Fi router/access point and you do not want the Comcast-supplied router to have Wi-Fi at all. Correct?

Comment: @DanielB Currently I'm using the Comcast router for guest wifi but I can move it to my Linksys mesh (easily I think). So yes: I'd rather use my own router for wifi and just need a modem (that doesn't leave unused channels on).

Comment: If you still have a Wi-Fi network active, it is a given the radio would not be disabled. Try disabling any user-configurable Wi-Fi on the Comcast device. If it then stays active you can proceed with Yorik’s answer.

Answer (score 1):

This is the standard for Comcast and it is part of how they can promise the roaming Comcast connectivity ("Wireless Internet on the Go"). The radio cannot be disabled, and any attempt to do so in their interface will only disable wifi for the local network.

I presume the public-facing wifi is on a VLAN or something.

The easiest way to fix this is to get your own DOCSIS device (aka modem). They have a pretty good list of supported consumer models and there are some decent ones for not a lot of money (just check to match the throughput to your plan). My daughter picked one up for about 80$, alongside another 80$ for a decent router. Compare this to the rental fee for their equipment, and it is basically a wash.

Comment: That's clearly the way to go. I'll just [replace the modem](https://www.netgear.com/home/wifi/modems/cm1000/) (and report back how that works).

Comment: When purchasing cable modems, ensure you check the amount of download/upload streams the modem has in conjunction with the throughput _(it's preferable to get one with more download and upload streams than the provider, as well as throughput that exceeds than the providers, to future-proof it for a few years)_